# React: Show MUI Autocomplete freeSolo with drop-down arrow

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am new to MUI, so need a little help.

I want to use `<Autocomplete freeSolo ...>` that shows a dropdown arrow icon like it were a combo-box mode.

[image]

Looks like `popupIcon` and `forcePopupIcon` props are being ignored in `freeSolo` mode.

Thanks!

Comment: I encountered a similar problem, and when I included the 'forcePopupIcon' prop, the icon became visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add your icon in `renderInput` prop of **Autocomplete**. Actually `Autocomplete` component is just a wrapper around `Textfield` component. In ***MUI V5***, You can add any icon at the start or end of it by targeting `Textfield` inside it. For your case check the example below.

```
import Autocomplete from '@mui/material/Autocomplete'
import InputAdornment from '@mui/material/InputAdornment'
import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField'
import ArrowDropDownIcon from '@mui/icons-material/ArrowDropDown'


<Autocomplete
    freeSolo
    options={myOptions}
    renderInput={(params) => (
      <TextField
        {...params}
        label="My label"
        InputProps={{ endAdornment: (
            <InputAdornment position="end">
              <ArrowDropDownIcon />
            </InputAdornment>
          ),
        }}
      />
    )}
  />
```

Comment: Let me add something interesting, keeping `freesolo` enabled, will not update your InputAdornment Icon position to up or down automatically, you have to programmatically make the arrow icon up or down, Render `ArrowDropDownIcon` or `ArrowDropUpIcon` based on `params.InputProps?.endAdornment?.props?.ownerState?.popupOpen` , Enjoy! :D

Comment: `<InputAdornment position="end">
 {castTo<ReactElement>(params?.InputProps?.endAdornment)?.props?.ownerState?.popupOpen ? (
   <ArrowDropUpIcon />
 ) : (
   <ArrowDropDownIcon />
 )}
  </InputAdornment>`

Answer (score 4):

Simply just add `forcePopupIcon` props.

```
<Autocomplete {...props} freeSolo forcePopupIcon />
```

Comment: This solution is great